# How to show a set is open using only the definition?

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation

We want to show that the set $S=\{x\in\mathbb R : 1<x<3\}$ is open using only the definition of open sets.

[ **Definition:**
A subset $S$ of $\mathbb R^n$ is open iff $\forall s\in S, \exists B_{\epsilon}(s)=\{x\in\mathbb R^n : ||x-s||<\epsilon\}$ such that $B_{\epsilon}(s)\subset S$ ]

**Proof:**

Start with an arbitrary $s\in S=(1,3)$ and an arbitrary $\epsilon>0$. Construct an $\epsilon$-ball $\{x\in\mathbb R : |x-s|<\epsilon\}$. Now, we have

$$|x-s|<\epsilon \iff -\epsilon<x-s<\epsilon \iff s-\epsilon<x<s+\epsilon$$

or $x\in(s-\epsilon,s+\epsilon)$. I am not sure how to conclude this proof. Essentially, how to conclude that $B_{\epsilon}\subset S$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, for every $ s\in S$, **there exist** $\varepsilon>0$, such that $B_\varepsilon(s) \subset S$. Just take $$\varepsilon=\min\{3-s,s-1\}$$ Then this $\varepsilon $ works!

---

**Verification:** Let $x \in B_\varepsilon(s)$.Then $|x-s|<\varepsilon.$ That is, $$x \in (s-\varepsilon,s+\varepsilon)$$.

If $s \geq 2$, then $\varepsilon=3-s.$In this case $$x \in (s-\varepsilon,s+\varepsilon)=(2s-3,3) \subset(1,3)$$

If $s \leq 2$, then $\varepsilon=s-1.$In this case also $$x \in (s-\varepsilon,s+\varepsilon)=(1,2s-1) \subset(1,3)$$

Comment: I notice that you wrote in bold "there exist $\varepsilon$". Is it a mistake to say "arbitrary $\varepsilon>0$?

Comment: No! you must find al least  one radius $r>0$ for which the ball around $s$ with radius $r$ is entirely contained in $S$. Here $\varepsilon$ plays the role of $r$

Comment: Would it be okay if we say $\varepsilon=\frac{1}{2}\min\{s-1,3-s\}$?

Comment: Yes, It also woks!